# Firestore Query Android WhereEqualTo

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I want to do is look up all the documents that "`usuarios`" equals "`amigos`".
The problem is that "`amigos`" is a list. I want you to bring all the documents of all the Strings(amigos) that you find on that list.
But I get this error:

> UNIMPLEMENTED: Unsupported FieldFilter value type: 9

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("eventos");

collectionReference.whereEqualTo("usuario", amigos).limit(15).orderBy("hora", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iant.png)

Comment: Could you show the full lines of logcat that show the error?  Is there a crash with an exception?  What actually is happening?

Comment: In the "WhereEqualTo", I want to send a Collection. That is the only error that I get in the addOnFailureListener.

Comment: As Doug asked, please paste your entire error in here.

Comment: It does not give me any error, it simply does not return any document. The only error that you get in the addOnFailureListener. The mistake that hits you, is the complete error. I have nothing else.

Comment: Please add you database structure to see how your `usuario` looks like.

Comment: There, add an image of the structure in Firestore. As you can see, what I want to do is get all the "Eventos" that the user that is inside the "Amigos" Collection has.

Comment: I'm sorry but all I can see in your database is the `eventos` collection which has a few documents beneath and each document has also a few properties. I cannot see any `Amigos` collection. Can you please be more specific? Or add a more detailed picture for a better understanding?

Comment: "Amigos" is simply an ArrayList. I want to bring all events that have in "Usuario" some String that is inside the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you are trying to filter your data using an `unsupported` type filter. Your `amigos` filed is an `ArrayList` and cannot be used to filter data. The second argument of the `whereEqualTo()` method can never be an `ArrayList`. You can filter only by [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). Unfortunatelly, the ArrayList is not suppoerted by Firestore.

Please see also [Query.whereEqualTo(String field, Object value)](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.25.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/class-use/Query.html):

> Creates and returns a new Query with the additional filter that documents must contain the specified field and the value should be equal to the specified value.

Comment: Ok, and what could I do to achieve it? Change the logic of the code?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the logic of your code. I recommend you filter your data using String values.